# Filter common sub-dictionary keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

How do i filter all common sub dictionary keys that exists in other sub dictionary keys in the parent dictionary

```
d = {
  '0': {'key_x': 0, 'key_y': 15, 'key_z': 41}
  '1': {'key_x': 5, 'key_y': 22}
  '2': {'key_x': 6, 'key_y': 41}
}

result ['key_x', 'key_y']
```

current solution is

```
intersect = {}
for k in corner_values.keys():
    for j in corner_values[k]:
        if j not in intersect:
            intersect[j] = 1
        else:
            intersect[j] += 1

for k in intersect:
    if intersect[k] != len(corner_values.keys()):
        del intersect[k]
```

Is there any simpler solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) the dictionaries to [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) and then [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) using [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
>>> from functools import reduce # if you are using Python 3
>>> d = {                       
...   '0': {'key_x': 0, 'key_y': 15, 'key_z': 41},
...   '1': {'key_x': 5, 'key_y': 22},
...   '2': {'key_x': 6, 'key_y': 41}
... }
>>> reduce(set.intersection, map(set, d.values()))
{'key_x', 'key_y'}
```

Note: In Python 3, `reduce` has been moved to `functools`.

Update: As seen in @John's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36769238/12892), `set.intersection` can handle an arbitrary number of sets, so the `reduce` is not even necessary. Just `set.intersection(*map(set, d.values()))`

Answer (score 3):

You can do a single [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) operation once you extract all the keys.  It's a one-liner then:

```
set.intersection(*(set(x) for x in d.itervalues()))
```

Breaking that down, the first part evaluated is this:

```
(set(x) for x in d.itervalues())
```

That's a generator which produces:

```
{'key_x', 'key_y'}, {'key_x', 'key_y', 'key_z'}, {'key_x', 'key_y'}
```

In Python 3 that generator is equivalent to:

```
map(set, d.values())
```

But in Python 2, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) is less efficient because it constructs a `list` that we don't need (as does [`values()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) instead of [`itervalues()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues)).

In any case, the results of that generator are passed to `set.intersection` (using the `*` argument unpacker) to do the heavy lifting in a single call.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know `intersection` worked "varargs"-style.

Comment: Python 2 has [`itertools.imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap)

Comment: Also even if you use a generator, when you call a function with it using `*`, its elements will still be stored in the container used for the arguments (`*args`). Nevertheless eliminating the intermediary `list` is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with `pandas`, the keys do not need to be ordered:

```
import pandas as pd

list(pd.DataFrame(d).dropna().index)

#['key_x', 'key_y']
```